# Azure Data Sync Rest API

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-sync

Is there a REST API that I can use instead of this application? I currently using the Data_Sync_Preview_REST_API.pdf but I think it doesn't have the capability to add your local server to Azure. I need the functionality with the arrows below for Register and Submit Agent Key via API or something that can Add an on-premises SQL Server database with API.

[image: Microsoft SQL Data Sync]